# Is there a way to automatically sign into a Apple ID Account for iCloud use inside of simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, simulator, fastlane

I know that you can sign in manually in the settings app on each simulator, wanted to know if there's some way to do this automatically. I've been using Fastlane to take screenshots. Now that I have an app that requires iCloud I'd have to go and manually sign in to an Apple ID account for each simulator, and language.

I've tried:

- Looking through simulator settings and Xcode settings, there appears
  to be no such option for any sort of "default" account.
- Searched Google/Stack overflow. I can't find anything relating to
  this subject aside from an apparent sign-on issue with Xcode 11 beta.
- From Caleb, Tried copying simulator preference files over from one simulator to
  the other, it appears to just overwrite these when loading up the new
  one.

### Update

I was not able to find a solution. I tried both of the below answers and was not able to get either working. I'll update this post if I figure out a way :)

Comment: Regarding _"Not sure why this was closed"_, your question was closed because it was seen as being opinion based. Use of the phrase _"Any suggestions"_ can be a red flag that you are just seeking general assistance and opinions, rather than looking for help with a specific problem. You might try rewording your question to remove _"Any suggestions?"_, and make it more focused. It would also be helpful to demonstrate that you have made some research effort before posting here.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'm not familiar with StackOverflow so I wasn't aware I should not ask for suggestions. I've attempted to reword the question including what I've tried, along with taking any suggestions out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what versions you are using but as of MacOS 10.13 and Xcode 9.1 there is no way to set an Apple ID a default and I can't find anything suggesting that this has been added in later versions. Sorry!

Comment: This is correct.  The answer is No just now.  Hopefully they'll change that soon.  They are working through some changes to the simulators, for example, audio player simulation is finally added.

Answer (score 0):

According to [*You don’t need GUI — how to control iOS Simulator from command line*](https://itnext.io/you-dont-need-gui-or-how-to-control-ios-simulator-from-command-line-bf5cfa60aed2), there's a preferences file for each simulator located at:

```
$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/$SIMULATOR_ID/data/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences
```

You could set up a simulator manually with whatever settings you need, then go grab that file and copy it to the corresponding location for each of your other simulators. I haven't checked that the iCloud account settings are in there, but you can look and see. Note that it's a binary file, so you'll need to use `plutil` to convert it to a human-readable property list if you want to look inside. The linked article gives some examples.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I did try that however could not get that to work.